# webrtc2sip compilation error

Tags: openssl, webrtc, redhat, rhel

When compiling webrtc2sip in Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.4 (Santiago)  following errors coming.

```
/usr/local/lib/libtinyNET.so: undefined reference to `EC_KEY_free'
/usr/local/lib/libtinyNET.so: undefined reference to `SSL_export_keying_material'
/usr/local/lib/libtinyNET.so: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_set_tlsext_use_srtp'
/usr/local/lib/libtinyNET.so: undefined reference to `SSL_get_selected_srtp_profile'
/usr/local/lib/libtinyNET.so: undefined reference to `EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [webrtc2sip] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/webrtc2sip'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Note: 
Doubango configuration options:

```
./configure --with-ssl --with-srtp --with-vpx --with-speexdsp --with-ffmpeg --with-opus
```

It compiled with out any issues

I saw some post on same error (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/doubango/qfuSwFnPjc8/lj6p1UTOkxcJ)

where i found it's because of two versions of ssl. But i'm not getting the exact thing for my case.

I've installed openssl by this steps:

```
wget http://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.1c.tar.gz
tar -xvzf openssl-1.0.1c.tar.gz
cd openssl-1.0.1c
./config shared --prefix=/usr/local --openssldir=/usr/local/openssl && make && make install
```

When i'm checking for openssl version i'm getting these informations:

```
[root@cluster ~]# openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012
[root@cluster ~]# rpm -qa | grep openssl
openssl098e-0.9.8e-17.el6_2.2.x86_64
openssl-1.0.0-27.el6.x86_64
openssl-devel-1.0.0-27.el6.x86_64
```

Can any body guide me how to solve this compilation issue ??

Comment: Can you re-run your failing make step but with a verbose shell, like `make SHELL="/bin/bash -x"`. The command that gives you thelinker error will then be printed. That could give you insight into which openssl library is used in the linking step.

Comment: I've tried to avoid using ssl , and that way it's working.
Both doubango frame work & webrtc2sip can be compiled with out ssl.
libssl.so under usr/lib64 & usr/local/lib64 can be deleted & compiled then after. Though who wants audio to support has to compile turn server using libssl which is mandatory .